# Array Randomica entre valores especificos

Tags: php

Gostaria de elaborar um array() onde eu possa colocar:
$arr = "argumento1, argumento2, argumento3..";
E retornar apenas 1, 2 ou 3, randomicamente.
Como é possível fazer?

Comment: usar o `rand()`/`mt_rand()` no indice tem algum problema?

Comment: Não sei como fazer

Comment: Se a chave for númerica, basta `$index = rand($min, $max); echo $arr[$index];` ou `$arr[rand(0,99)];`

Comment: Seria isso? `$a = array('PHP','Java','C#'); echo $a[array_rand($a)];` https://ideone.com/Tq2Xks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias e várias alternativas.

**random_int (PHP 7):**

```
$array = ['um', 'array', 'qualquer'];

// Contagem de elementos da array:
$contagem = count($array);

// Gera a "randomização" (ex. '2'):
$gerador = random_int(0, ($contagem - 1));

# É necessário subtrair um porque existem 3 elementos, porém array começa em 0 até 2, ao invés de 0 até 3. Portanto reduzindo 1, irá fazer com que entre na condição de 0 até 2. ;)

// Seleciona o item gerado previamente (ex. 'qualquer'):
$final = $array[$gerador];
```

> Este método (random_int) é supostamente o mais seguro!

[Veja mais na documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.random-int.php)

**array_rand (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7):**

```
$array = ['um', 'array', 'qualquer'];

// Gera a "randomização" (ex. '2'):
$gerador = array_rand($array);

// Seleciona o item gerado previamente (ex. 'qualquer'):
$final = $array[$gerador];
```

[Veja mais na documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-rand.php)

**mt_rand (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7):**

```
$array = ['um', 'array', 'qualquer'];

// Contagem de elementos da array:
$contagem = count($array);

// Gera a "randomização" (ex. '2'):
$gerador = mt_rand(0, ($contagem - 1) );

# É necessário subtrair um porque existem 3 elementos, porém array começa em 0 até 2, ao invés de 0 até 3. Portanto reduzindo 1, irá fazer com que entre na condição de 0 até 2. ;)

// Seleciona o item gerado previamente (ex. 'qualquer'):
$final = $array[$gerador];
```

[Veja mais na documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mt-rand.php)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

**[array_rand](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-rand.php)**

```
//Criando array
$a = array("red","green","blue","yellow","brown");

//Número máximo do rand
$max = (count($a) - 1);

//Resultado randômico
echo rand(0, $max);
```

Comment: `echo $a[rand(0, $max)];`